# Import node module conditionally based on node version

Tags: node.js

I'm in a situation where we have different environments running different versions of Node and I would like to be able to conditionally import certain modules based on the version of node that is running.

I tried doing this with the following block of code, but it results in an error

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

```
let ver = process.version.slice(1,ver.length).split('.');
if (parseInt(ver[0]) < 7) {
  import 'babel-polyfill'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional `import` is only allowed as dynamic imports, which are supported with Node.js experimental ES module support. The problem with dynamic imports is that they are asynchronous. Since a polyfill should be applied to all application, this propagates dynamic imports to all module imports. I.e.

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import * as foo from './foo';
import * as bar from './bar';
...
```

becomes

```
(async () => {
  let ver = process.version.slice(1,ver.length).split('.');
  if (parseInt(ver[0]) < 7) {
    await import 'babel-polyfill';
  }

  const foo = await import('./foo');
  const bar = await import('./bar');
  ...
})()
.catch(console.error);
```

So it's still a good idea to use `require` for conditional imports in Node.js *non-native* ES modules, because ES modules are supposed to be transpiled to CommonJS and `require` with Babel:

```
let ver = process.version.slice(1,ver.length).split('.');
if (parseInt(ver[0]) < 7) {
  require('babel-polyfill');
}

import * as foo from './foo';
import * as bar from './bar';
...
```

Most importantly, **a polyfill shouldn't be conditionally imported because it's purpose is to polyfill missing features**. It does nothing with features that don't need to be polyfilled. If some parts of `babel-polyfill` are unused but cause problems in later Node versions, import only parts that are needed in current application. `babel-polyfill` is just a wrapper around `core-js` polyfill which is fine-grained and can be narrowed down to polyfilling specific features.

Answer (score 3):

There is a babel-preset for this - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import. You can use it as following -

```
let ver = process.version.slice(1,ver.length).split('.');
if (parseInt(ver[0] < 7)) {
    import('babel-polyfill')
    .then(result => {
       console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: This may be not a good idea because the code that depend on dynamically imported module should be evaluated in `then`. And this is *all code* for a polyfill.